# delete key prints "~" in putty

Tags: putty

i am SSHing to a RHEL-3 box using Putty. Backspace works correctly, but when I press the "Delete" key the deletion does not happen. Instead, it prints "~" on the screen.

Thanks in advance,
Ajay

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing your options in the PuTTY keyboard pannel?

Alternatively, you can try to create a ~/.inputrc file on the RH box, with the following contents:

"\e[3~": delete-char

Once you've created the ~/.inputrc file, restart the shell.

Comment: This didn't work :(

Comment: You probably forgot to restart the shell. (^X ^R also works.) Also, it's supposed to be `~/.inputrc` - in your homedir, not in `/`.

Comment: This worked for me in the shell, but VIM still has the error. Thanks for the help!