# Insert key prints ~ in shell

Tags: putty

How to fix this one ?

Comment: Related question, s/insert/delete: http://serverfault.com/questions/109712/delete-key-prints-in-putty

Answer (score 1):

Putty is using a different keymap than your remote server expects.  I don't think you *can* fix it per-se... as it's working as designed.  The question is, how do you implement keyboard keys that are handled by the underlying OS on a remote machine which may function differently?  You'll find that nearly all (if not all) ssh clients have variations on how keyboard inputs are translated over the wire and how the remote host understands them.  There might be a way to assign a different character map to putty... but I find this is more work than it's worth.  Many times different applications behave differently with regard to the keymaps.  (i.e. in nano & vi... the insert key behaves one way... in the shell completely differently)

Your best bet, is to find another way to accomplish the same task without using the insert key.

Comment: Who uses the insert key anymore? [/snark] This is honestly not an unreasonable suggestion, IMO.

Comment: I agree it's not unreasonable to ask for... but the reality is that there is no universal key-map for ssh... There are several variations and somethings just don't play nice.